# Count Users By Date Range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, count, linq-to-entities

I have the following User entity:

```
public class User
{
  public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

How can I count the users by Age range? Something like:

```
0 to 5
5 to 15
...
```

I tried the following:

```
var usersByAge = context.Users.GroupBy(x => x.Info.Birthday).Count();
```

But this groups the users by their birthday and counts it counts by day.
It counts by day because the time is always null ...

But I need to Group by Age range. 
For example, get the span in Years from birthday to DateTime.Now. 
Then group by "0-5", "5-15", ... And then count.

How can I do this? Please, let me know if it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can select filter them like this :

```
var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
var users = yourUserCollection.Count(x =>
    x.BirthDay.Year - year >= 5 && 
    x.BirthDay.Year - year <= 11);
```

Comment: The posted code will count users that are older then 5 years old, correct? I need to count users in date range. Count users between 0 and 5, between 6 and 15, between 16 and 30 ... In age ranges. Does this make sense?

Comment: just add "&&" operator for the second condition

Comment: Yes, but how to do this for 10 Age Ranges in one query without having 10 queries similar to yours? Is it possible?